# Windows 7 BSOD Crashes

Tags: windows-7, crash, bsod, debug

I recently upgraded to Windows 7 64 doing a clean install from Vista 64 and ever since I keep getting random blue screen crashes. I have the feeling it's caused by my video card but everything has the most up-to-date drivers for Windows 7 64 bit.

Here is the memory dump from my most recent crash:

```
MEMORY_MANAGEMENT (1a)
    # Any other values for parameter 1 must be individually examined.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000041790, The subtype of the bugcheck.
Arg2: fffffa8001990b90
Arg3: 000000000000ffff
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------

PEB is paged out (Peb.Ldr = 000007ff`fffd9018).  Type ".hh dbgerr001" for details
PEB is paged out (Peb.Ldr = 000007ff`fffd9018).  Type ".hh dbgerr001" for details

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x1a_41790

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VISTA_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  csrss.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80002cff26e to fffff80002c8cf00

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`0299ae38 fffff800`02cff26e : 00000000`0000001a 00000000`00041790 fffffa80`01990b90 00000000`0000ffff : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff880`0299ae40 fffff800`02cc05d9 : fffffa80`00000000 00000000`01e73fff 00000000`00000000 fffff960`0023653f : nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x339d6
fffff880`0299b000 fffff800`02fa2e50 : fffffa80`09140c90 0007ffff`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!MiRemoveMappedView+0xd9
fffff880`0299b120 fffff960`002e381b : fffff900`00000000 fffffa80`07c85d10 00000000`00000001 fffff900`c1e56cd0 : nt!MiUnmapViewOfSection+0x1b0
fffff880`0299b1e0 fffff960`002b4fc1 : 00000000`00000000 fffff900`00000000 fffff900`c1e56cd0 00000000`00000000 : win32k!SURFACE::bUnMapImmediate+0x5b
fffff880`0299b210 fffff960`002b527b : fffff900`c07fdd10 fffff8a0`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : win32k!bMigrateSurfaceForConversion+0x5ad
fffff880`0299b340 fffff960`002dc3e3 : fffff900`00000000 fffff900`c1e5c010 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : win32k!pConvertDfbSurfaceToDibInternal+0x1cb
fffff880`0299b420 fffff960`002b5319 : fffffa80`07c7f470 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000282 : win32k!MulConvertChildRedirectionDfbSurfaceToDib+0x53
fffff880`0299b460 fffff960`002b1267 : fffff900`c0132010 fffff900`c0132010 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : win32k!pConvertDfbSurfaceToDib+0x41
fffff880`0299b490 fffff960`002b1b1f : fffff900`c0132010 00000000`00000001 fffff900`c24cc280 fffff900`c0132010 : win32k!bDynamicRemoveAllDriverRealizations+0x4f
fffff880`0299b4c0 fffff960`00273bb9 : 00000000`00000000 fffff900`00000000 fffff900`00000000 00000000`00000000 : win32k!bDynamicModeChange+0x1d7
fffff880`0299b5a0 fffff960`000baa2d : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 07cd8220`00000003 : win32k!DrvInternalChangeDisplaySettings+0xc7d
fffff880`0299b7e0 fffff960`001a2c41 : 00000000`00000040 fffff900`c00bf010 00000000`00000000 07cd8220`00000003 : win32k!DrvChangeDisplaySettings+0x62d
fffff880`0299b9c0 fffff960`001a2e9e : fffffa80`07cd8220 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 fffff800`02f6fec3 : win32k!xxxInternalUserChangeDisplaySettings+0x329
fffff880`0299ba80 fffff960`001a033a : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00998b21`81a100b6 00000000`00000040 : win32k!xxxUserChangeDisplaySettings+0x92
fffff880`0299bb70 fffff960`001a053a : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : win32k!xxxRemoteSetDisconnectDisplayMode+0x42
fffff880`0299bbb0 fffff960`00183ea6 : 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`06efeb60 fffff880`0299bca0 00000000`00000005 : win32k!xxxRemoteDisconnect+0x1c2
fffff880`0299bbf0 fffff800`02c8c153 : fffffa80`06efeb60 00000000`00000005 00000000`00000020 00000000`00000000 : win32k!NtUserCallNoParam+0x36
fffff880`0299bc20 000007fe`fd6b3d3a : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13
00000000`027cf798 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x7fe`fd6b3d3a


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
win32k!SURFACE::bUnMapImmediate+5b
fffff960`002e381b f6477401        test    byte ptr [rdi+74h],1

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  4

SYMBOL_NAME:  win32k!SURFACE::bUnMapImmediate+5b

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: win32k

IMAGE_NAME:  win32k.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4a5bc5e0

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x1a_41790_win32k!SURFACE::bUnMapImmediate+5b

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x1a_41790_win32k!SURFACE::bUnMapImmediate+5b

Followup: MachineOwner
```

Comment: Up-to-date drivers won't help failing hardware, no matter how much you try.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [BlueScreenView](http://nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) to analyze the BSOD, and post some more info:

> BlueScreenView scans all your minidump
>   files created during 'blue screen of
>   death' crashes, and displays the
>   information about all crashes in one
>   table. For each crash, BlueScreenView
>   displays the minidump filename, the
>   date/time of the crash, the basic
>   crash information displayed in the
>   blue screen (Bug Check Code and 4
>   parameters), and the details of the
>   driver or module that possibly caused
>   the crash (filename, product name,
>   file description, and file
>   version). For each crash
>   displayed in the upper pane, you can
>   view the details of the device drivers
>   loaded during the crash in the lower
>   pane. **BlueScreenView also mark the drivers that their addresses found in
>   the crash stack, so you can easily locate the suspected drivers that
>   possibly caused the crash.**